# Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger autoConfirmUser not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

When creating a new cognito user, I would like to confirm their account through the Pre Sign-up lambda. It looks as follows:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
  event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
  callback(null, event);
};
```

The above function is called (checked with logs) and the event is returned and the user created without any errors. However, when looking at the user in cognito the account status is still set to:

```
FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD
```

In case it is of any help, the adminCreateUser function looks as follows:

```
adminCreateUser({
  UserPoolId: process.env.AUTH_COGNITO_USERPOOLID,
  Username: email,
  DesiredDeliveryMediums: ['EMAIL'],
  ForceAliasCreation: true,
  TemporaryPassword: temporaryPassword,
  UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: email,
    },
    {
      Name: 'email_verified',
      Value: 'true'
    },
  ],
  ClientMetadata: {
    role,
  },
})
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Pre Sign-up trigger you can only set email/phone to `verified` or user status to `CONFIRMED`. Password change will be required in any case if you use `AdminCreateUser` API.

Couple options you can try:

- Use `SignUp` API instead: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html
- Use subsequent call to `AdminSetUserPassword` API to change user password after `AdminCreateUser`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html